# Reminder to mark question as answered

Tags: feature-request

I've gone through all the similar posts to this but can't find something with the same suggestion. I'm noticing a trend where OPs think that upvoting an is answer is marking it as answered.

I understand the reasons for them to be able to upvote an answer and not mark it as answered. However it might be helpful if, when the OP is upvoting an answer, they are reminded to and given the option to mark it as answered.

Comment: Isn't this already done?

Comment: If it is, I haven't seen it and it doesn't appear to be effective. I think there is a reminder in the profile a day or so after asking the question.

Comment: @VJo: I seem to recall that it's the reverse: mark an answer accepted, and you get prompted to upvote it.

Comment: @BoltClock There's a notification in your profile and elsewhere if your question has gone without an accepted answer for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the mark down. A bit harsh as you can't have read my post. I think my suggestion still stands. I notice alot of accounts that ask one question and never come back (too see the notices) yet they upvote the answer thinking thats marking it as answered.

Comment: I have a similar question, which is whether, after a user implicitly accepts an answer via a comment, e.g. "Awesome, that works!  Thanks." is there an appropriate way to encourage the user to accept the answer (beyond the system alerts noted here).  Is there a reputation level at which non-OP users can mark questions Accepted?

Comment: @Grace Note, the notification is good, but someone would have to log in to see it.  Some people may only ever ask one question and never get 'addicted' to SO.  I wish there was a way to send a message to a user to ask them to accept an answer.