# Ask for a resolved mark button

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

It should be a good idea to have some mechanism to request to the user who asked a question to mark the question as resolved. I know not all questions are resolved but some of them a lot of times are clearly resolved and the answer is still unmarked.

I'm talking about not only a reminder like the people asked for at [Reminder to mark question as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113663/reminder-to-mark-question-as-answered), I'm talking about some kind of button that can be pushed by other users who think the question is clearly resolved and if an important number of users (this is the more difficult point... to determine how many is needed to do this) click on that "ask for a resolved mark", the question must be marked as resolved on any answer or a consequence can happen. This consequence could be the loss of some reputation points or something like that.

It's only an idea that must be polished. What do you think?

Comment: Why the people is voting negatively to this question? I'm not agree with that. I think it could be very useful :/ . Too much demanding and rude people here...

Comment: Voting on meta means (dis)agreement. Apparently some users disagree with you.

Comment: Yeah, it seems a good practice to blame people that is trying to help and improve the site. I love this place.

Comment: We aren't blaming anyone, we just disagree. FWIW, I didn't vote on your question.

Comment: I don'k now who is doing that... (maybe a button to know that could be better too... xd), but it seems the "automatic mechanisnm" is: `if the asker has poor reputation; then; vote negatively; else; vote positively`without consider if is really interesting. :/

Comment: How do you think I once started? With 100K rep? No, with just as much reputation as you.

Comment: I know. I'm only talking about the newbies on this place has more difficulties to "grow up" because of the prejudices. I really appreciate your honest opinion and thank you for not voting negatively. I hope that means you agreed with the answer. But is really difficult sometimes to contribute. I'm not sure what is better for me... to delete this post now... or let it... you will see the negative votes increasing and increasing... and why? only for trying to improve the site. I really think is unfair :(

Comment: Okay, so we disagree your 'improvement' is an improvement to the site. I have done some feature requests in the past which I thought were a good idea, but failed for good reasons. Those also received quite some downvotes. Learn from it and move on.

Comment: Ok thanks again for the info. I'll try to do my best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> some kind of button that can be pushed for other users who think the question is clearly resolved and if an important number of users

No. That defeats the purpose of that check mark. That check mark means *This answer helped me the most and solved the issue I had* (from the question owner point-of-view). The check mark doesn't mean anything more. It doesn't mean the community finds it the best answer (upvotes are for that). So no-one besides the question owner should press that button.

> the question must be marked as resolved on any answer or a consequence can happen

Why? If I am not totally satisfied with your answer, why should it hurt me? Maybe *other* users found it helpful, but I didn't. Why should it cost me anything not accepting your answer? We like it better the other way around: reward positive behavior. Accepting an answer (which is not your own) gives you +2 reputation.

I think we just have to live with the fact that some users don't bother to accept or vote on an answer. I hope that the community can correct that by do their part of voting on posts (either up or down).

Comment: I understand your point of view... and maybe you are right... but look at the negative votes of my question... you said "If I am not totally satisfied with your answer, why should it hurt me?" and obviously I'm not agree with the people that voted me negatively on this question and is hurting me... so makes no much sense. Think about it... or better do what everybody do here... vote negatively instead of think a little bit.

Answer (score 5):

We already have two mechanisms in place to check if a question is 'resolved' by a certain answer:

- the asker of the question can accept an answer
- everybody with 15 or more reputation can upvote an answer

A large number of upvotes already indicates if an answer is a good *candidate* of resolving the issue in the question. Even then, it's still *no guarantee* that it will solve the actual issues of the OP (or future readers with the same problem). A third resolution/voting mechanism as you propose won't solve that.

Comment: I know the upvotes are good... but even with a lot of them the question is unmarked as resolved. I'm talking about educate users that ask to force them to "finish" marking the questions. So many users only asking and after getting the answer don't mark. Thank you for your answer. Will see if maybe other can be more accurate for me

Answer (score 3):

I think it'd be great to have a button like this.  The button should of course do literally nothing when pushed, but if there is a button to request that the author of the question mark an answer as accepted then people are likely to push it, rather than posting comments to badger the OP to accept an answer, so having a button falsely purporting to do that for them should reduce the amount of these types of inappropriate comments while still giving the people that want to post them the satisfaction that they want.